# Error when Registering type with Unity through configuration file

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

This is my configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>
  <unity>
    <containers>
      <container>
        <types>
          <type type="InterfacesLibrary.ICalculator, InterfacesLibrary" mapTo="CalculatorLibrary.Calculator, CalculatorLibrary"/>
          <type type="InterfacesLibrary.ICalculatorReplLoop, InterfacesLibrary" mapTo="CalculatorLibrary.CalculatorReplLoop, CalculatorLibrary"/>
          <type type="InterfacesLibrary.IInputService, InterfacesLibrary" mapTo="InputOutputLibrary.ConsoleInputService, InputOutputLibrary"/>
          <type type="InterfacesLibrary.IOutputService, InterfacesLibrary" mapTo="InputOutputLibrary.ConsoleOutputService, InputOutputLibrary"/>
          <type type="InterfacesLibrary.IInputParserService, InterfacesLibrary" mapTo="CalcCommandParsingLib.InputParserService, CalcCommandParsingLib"/>
        </types>
      </container>
    </containers>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

and the main method:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            UnityConfigurationSection configSection = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");

            configSection.Configure(container, string.Empty);

            ICalculatorReplLoop loop = container.Resolve<ICalculatorReplLoop>();

            loop.Run();
        }
```

it fails here:

```
configSection.Configure(container, string.Empty);
```

and the error message is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll
>
> Additional information: The type name or alias
>   CalculatorLibrary.Calculator, CalculatorLibrary could not be resolved.
>   Please check your configuration file and verify this type name.

if I use this in my Main() method without the configuration file, then it works fine:

```
container.RegisterType<ICalculator, Calculator>();
        container.RegisterType<IInputService, ConsoleInputService>();
        container.RegisterType<IOutputService, ConsoleOutputService>();
        container.RegisterType<IInputParserService, InputParserService>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register the classes programmatically Visual Studio can see the hard dependencies and, during compilation, copy all relevant assemblies to the output directory so that the types can be resolved at runtime.

However, when using a configuration, Visual Studio does not know about the (soft) dependencies.  So, even though, there is a reference added, Visual Studio does not copy the appropriate assemblies required by the configuration file and Unity throws an exception saying that it cannot resolve the type.  i.e. the InterfacesLibrary is copied but the other implementation assemblies are not copied because they are never referenced in the code.

One solution is to add a post build event to copy all required assemblies that are only referenced via the configuration.  Another approach is to reference the assembly in the code so that Visual Studio will see the dependency and copy the assembly.  A typical approach is something like this:

```
// Force copy of soft dependency CalculatorLibrary assembly
private static Type calculatorType = typeof(CalculatorLibrary.Calculator);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the example I have is from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_64FFdeJwcM and the main goal was not to have to use any reference to the 'CalculatorLibrary' and all other libraries by using the configuration file. It just somehow works magically in the video

Comment: You don't *have* to reference CalculatorLibrary -- you just have to ensure the assembly is deployed at runtime.  You can do that anyway you wish. e.g. hard reference, post build command, manual copy, deployment script, etc.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I just checked the bin/debug folder and there was no CalculatorLibrary.dll. I manually copied it from previous build and now it works. Thank you for your help.